# iOS Notification on battery level

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, battery

I'm developing an iOS app, and I'm looking for a way to make a notification appear when a specific battery level is reached. So my app has to do that while in background.

I found a tutorial with local notification, but the only way to make it appear is to set up a precise date and time. 
If you have informations about it, it'll be very sweet.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I edit the SitePoint mobile channel (disclaimer) and I know we've had several articles on this topic, so do either of these:

http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-the-battery-status-api/
http://www.sitepoint.com/5-javascript-apis-empower-mobile-web-pages/
http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-battery-status-api/

Help?

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution with background mode.

Comment: @User2 Can you please put there your solution? Thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution for this. You have to run time to time your app in order to achieve this and check if desired battery charge level has reached then post an immediate notification if it's the case.

As a working case you can use `background fetch` mode to wake app at specific time intervals and do the required battery level check. Be aware that `background fetch` doesn't provide a consistent time period, you can't wake up app each 15 minutes or 30 minutes, the time is calculated by the system and it's variable, this can make app to "miss" the target level.

You can use also, silent `remote notifications` which wake your app when delivered, you do the check and present the local notification if needed. This is more reliable than the first case but of course you need to setup a push notification server or use a service which implements this.

Honestly being you won't find a 100% reliable way to do this, so if this is a primary feature of your app think twice before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check battery Level in back ground. When it will reach specific level as per your requirement immediately fire Local Notification.

Comment: If I'm right, I only got to enable battery monitoring, and make a notification observer on the battery level, and this notification can be pushed even if my app is running in background ?